# NoClassDefFoundError (unknown source) when starting new Activity android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to start an activity. Here is my code:

```
btnShowOnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PlacesMapActivity.class);
            // Sending user current geo location
            i.putExtra("user_latitude", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
            i.putExtra("user_longitude", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));

            // passing near places to map activity
            i.putExtra("near_places", nearPlaces);
            // staring activity
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

The Manifest xml file looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!--  Add Google Map Library -->
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />



    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- SinglePlaceActivity -->
    <activity android:name=".SinglePlaceActivity" android:label="Place Details">
    </activity>

    <!-- PlacesMapActivity -->
    <activity android:name=".PlacesMapActivity" android:label="Near Places Map View">
    </activity>

</application>

<!-- Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Access Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

It compiles without problems, but when I want to create a new intent, I'm getting an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/androidhive/googleplacesandmaps/PlacesMapActivity Error. Does anybody know what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a linking problem. If you use eclipse, make sure you add the correct jar files to your project. Else make sure you define your classpath correctly